# Forward incoming packets from port 25565 to natted internal client? IPTables

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, nat, port-forwarding

I have been learning to use iptables recently and i made a small nat network in virtualbox. I have a Debian server Natting for the internal clients. One of the internal clients is hosting a minecraft server for testing.

What im wanting to do is have any incoming connections using port 25565 going in eth0 from the debian server, to forward them *specifically* to the internal minecraft server (192.168.200.4) out eth1. Just like you would in a regular Linksys router.

What i had come up with, but doesnt actually work was:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 --dport 25565 -o eth1 -d 192.168.200.4 -j ACCEPT
```

Then i read in the errors and other tuts out there, that its actually POSTROUTING/PREROUTING that i need to use. so then i tried:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 25565 -o eth1 -d 192.168.200.4 -j ACCEPT
```

Now obviously none of these work, but i want to know if i am in the right track?

Here is a diagram of the virtual network so yall can see it visually:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9rZS.jpg

Currently, the iptables config looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target      prot  opt  source                    destination
ACCEPT      all   --   anywhere                  anywhere                 
ACCEPT      all   --   anywhere                  anywhere                 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT      all   --   anywhere                  anywhere                 tcp dpt:telnet

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target      prot  opt  source                    destination
ACCEPT      all   --   anywhere                  anywhere                 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT      all   --   anywhere                  anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target      prot  opt  source                    destination
```

Any additional details will be gladly added :)

***(Anything in the INPUT chain is just other rules i was messing with earlier, originally, the only rules it had were the ones under the FORWARD chain)***

**This is the tutorial that i had followed for NAT:**
http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scheme, your External IP is incorrect : `192.168.1.161` is an internal IP.

You have a real External (public) IP : check it with e.g http://www.whatismyip.com (hope it is a fixed one).

First, you need to use the `PREROUTING` chain to DNAT your External IP to your Internal IP :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d $PUBLIC_IP --destination-port 25565 -j DNAT --to 192.168.200.4:25565
```

Then, you need to allow packet forwarding between interfaces from source to target :

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -o eth1 -d 192.168.200.4 --destination-port 25565 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

However, surch Google about how to do this for a Web Server and you will find a lot of ressources (on this site also). The logic remains the same.

Comment: oh no, i know 192.168.1.xx is a class c private IP, in the schema im just using it as an external. but what just hit me is that, it might not work becuase private ip's arent routable. i would have to  either use a nat network from virtual box and add one more external host as the minecraft client and try it that way. but ill try what you posted. thanks!

Comment: oh, what... the nat in vbox is a 10 network, also private. nvm. ill just try this then